# push my changes made in gerrit to github repository

Tags: git, github, gerrit

I am new to this gerrit thing so need some help here. So here is a the scenario,

I have a existing client repository that I am working on and wanted to add a review system on top of it.

So I configure gerrit locally on my server, installed the github plugin as well.

Now I am able to login into gerrit with my github credentials, import the repositories.

Clone the repo using my local gerrit url http://gerrit-server:/8080/project-name.git. I can make changes to this clone commit and push the changes as well.

Now these changes are reflected onto my gerrit repository.

But once everything is reviewed and pushed I want this change to be reflected on the client repository too which is hosted on github. How do I make this happen?
Is there a way to sync my gerrit repo with the github repo?

I tried using replication plugin for the same but that does not seem to be making sense. Is there any other plugin for the same of its expected to be done manually or through some scripts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had this working for a long time and as far as I remember, then I told gerrit that it should connect with github after that whenever I made a submit in gerrit, then it would be pushed to github - however if the push contains files larger than 100m then it will break the connection with github and replication will no longer work - unless you remove the large file, then you can resume and submit will work again.
Unfortunately pt. the submit to github is NOT working - I suspect some changes have been made in either gerrit or github, so for me submit now nolonger works - I however then manually make a git pull upstream  on github repository where upstream is gerrit repository, then make a git push to update github - cumbersome, but it works, and hopefully soon the auto replication will be fixed

Comment: also if you make a git push outside the gerrit - directly to github, then this could also stop the replication process - it is somewhat unstable, so be careful on what you do when pushing to github